# Getting selected text data with swift macOS

Tags: swift, macos, accessibility

I am trying to get selected text data(browser/pdf/all) in macOS app. I used this code but its not working

```
 let error = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(self.systemWideElement, kAXFocusedUIElementAttribute as CFString, &self.focusedElement)
 if (error != .success){
     print(error)
     print("Couldn't get the focused element. Probably a webkit application")
 } else {
     var selectedRangeValue : AnyObject?
     let selectedRangeError = AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(self.focusedElement as! AXUIElement, kAXSelectedTextRangeAttribute as CFString, &selectedRangeValue)
     if (selectedRangeError == .success){
         var selectedRange : CFRange?
         AXValueGetValue(selectedRangeValue as! AXValue, AXValueType(rawValue: kAXValueCFRangeType)!, &selectedRange)
         var selectRect = CGRect()
         var selectBounds : AnyObject?
         let selectedBoundsError = AXUIElementCopyParameterizedAttributeValue(self.focusedElement as! AXUIElement, kAXBoundsForRangeParameterizedAttribute as CFString, selectedRangeValue!, &selectBounds)
         if (selectedBoundsError == .success){
             AXValueGetValue(selectBounds as! AXValue, .cgRect, &selectRect)
             //do whatever you want with your selectRect
             print(selectRect)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: How is it not working? Any errors?

Comment: "Couldn't get the focused element. Probably a webkit application" Its not working. Anyone have solution for this ? I want to get selected text data from global

Comment: What is the value of `error`?